# Vim forgets yanked text. All the time

Tags: vim

This is what I do:

1. Go into visual mode
2. Highlight some text
3. Press <kbd>y</kbd> (or <kbd>x</kbd>)
4. Go back into command mode
5. Press <kbd>p</kbd>

About 2 times out of 5 Vim forgets the text and usually just pastes a newline.  It's very frustrating.  Is this a bug?  I can't seem to reproduce it, it seems totally random.

Comment: I doubt very highly this is actually what's going on. I suspect you are inadvertently yanking something, have a macro that clears the register, or have other keystrokes involved that invoke alternate registers. The thing to do is pay way more attention to every command you do leading up to the perceived failure and figure out which one is touching the registers.

Comment: Which platform? Which version of Vim? Console mode vim or graphical gVim? It still seems unlikely that the above is the whole story, but more information about your environment might help people with idea to try to help.

Comment: About two times out of five are you accidentally hitting `o` instead of `p` ?!

Comment: You could yank text 5 times and paste the content of the default register on your question as well. The default register is `"` and you can access its content through `:reg "`.

Comment: @Prince actually, that's very possible.  I'd like to think that part of it is sometimes using some of the commands listed below without thinking.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you run `p`, it pastes from the default register. The contents of the default register are altered each time you do any of the following:

- `y` to yank
- `d{motion}` to delete
- `x` to delete a character
- `c{motion}` to delete and enter insert mode
- `s` to delete a character and enter insert mode
- in visual mode, `p` will overwrite the selected text with the default register, and overwrite the default register with the text that was selected (or in simpler terms, it swaps the default register and the selected text).

With so many commands touching the default register, it is quite frequently the case that it doesn't contain what you expect it to. For this reason, it's good to get into the habit of always specifying a register when you delete or yank something that you intend to paste later.

Try this instead:

1. Go into visual mode
2. Highlight some text
3. Press `"ay` (or `"ax`)
4. Go back into command mode
5. Press `"ap`

Comment: The numbered registers (`:help quote_number`) might also be useful.

Comment: I think specifying a register for every yank and delete is a little overkill, but would definitely get the job done.  People on less capable editors only _have_ the one default register to work with, and yet the world goes on.

Comment: Awesome, OK thanks.  I knew some commands were modifying the clipboard buffer but I didn't know all of them.  I'll use the named registers for important chunks of text from now on.

Answer (score 0):

You might find [yankstack](https://github.com/maxbrunsfeld/vim-yankstack) useful. With it installed, after you paste with `p`, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> to cycle through recently yanked text.

---

Or a simpler solution is to paste from the 0 register:

From `:help "0`

> Numbered register 0 contains the text from the most recent yank
>   command, unless the command specified another register with ["x].

I do this very often, so I have this map:

```
" Paste last yanked item
noremap <Leader>p "0p
noremap <Leader>P "0P
```